# Looking for sample Spring MVC with Cassandra example

Tags: spring-mvc, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am looking for sample Spring MVC with Cassandra project. I see many example with Spring and Cassandra but not with Spring MVC. Just wanted to see configuration and one transaction with Cassandra.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Whats wrong in this question? Why did it got down voted?

Answer (score 0):

Just look into [Spring Data Example repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/cassandra/example).